# Call TextView from MainActivity to Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

Is it possible to call `MainActivity` control `TextView` to `Fragment` ? I don't know whether this is possible or not.

There is `DrawerLayout` and It contains `TextView`. validation layout contains `TextView`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightish" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/lightish" />

        <include layout="@layout/validation" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSlider"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/dark_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now, I am calling `Fragment` in `FrameLayout` when anyone click on slider menu item. I want to Find that `TextView` control in Fragment. Is it possible, if yes then how ? It is like calling `MasterPage` control in `WebForm` in `Asp.net`.

Comment: `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textId)`. You can find views of activity in fragment using `getActivity()`

Comment: in onViewCreated(View v){ v.findViewById(...);}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah its possible.

you can try like this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtpoint);
textview.setText("Something you write");
```

Comment: Thank you. It has solved my problem. Now, when I am calling `OptionsMenu` from Slider, that time it is not displaying anything in `TextView`. What changes should i make for this ?